# Unable to View Xamarin.Form Preview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio On Mac. Xamaring version is 6.1.2. I am unable to view Preview of Xamarin Form. Please see the attached screen shot and let me know if there is something missing. I have checked for updates and everything is updated as it can be seen below.

"Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.175" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you try right clicking the file in the Solution window and selecting Open with - XAML Viewer? Note you will need to close the file if it is already open in the text editor.

Comment: I got the problem solved by closing all the windowns, right clicking on xaml and opened in xaml preview. It Worked :)

Comment: Great. In Xamarin Studio 6.1 you have to explicitly open the xaml in the xaml previewer. In Xamarin Studio 6.2 it will open in the xaml previewer by default.